# Downloading network file fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webclient

The following code gives the following exception and inner exception:

```
webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
var uri = new Uri("\\NetworkPC\File.ppt");
webClient.DownloadFile(uri, "\\NetworkPC\App\File.ppt");
```

I tried using Impersonation but got the same error:

```
var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
using (identity.Impersonate())
{
    webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    var uri = new Uri("\\NetworkPC\File.ppt");
    webClient.DownloadFile(uri, "\\NetworkPC\App\File.ppt");
}
```

I am able to access the file "\NetworkPC\File.ppt" from Windows Explorer. What am I missing here?

Application details:
ASP.NET MVC .NET 4.0

IIS Application setting:
Pass-through authentication

**Exception:**

```
Message=Access to the path '\\NetworkPC\File.ppt' is denied.
Source=System
TargetSite=Void DownloadFile(System.Uri, System.String)
```

**Inner Exception:**

```
Message=Access to the path '\\NetworkPC\File.ppt' is denied.
Source=System
StackTrace=   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
TargetSite=Void .ctor(System.Net.FileWebRequest, System.Uri, System.IO.FileAccess, Boolean)
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on feedback tried using File.Exists and File.Copy instead of WebClient.
File.Exists returns false. The previous ASP solution used a COM component ASPUpload to check if file exists and copy operations.

Comment: The code you've provided won't even compile - the string literals are invalid. Assuming you've basically got SMB shares, those aren't URIs of the form WebClient supports, as far as I'm aware. You may well find that `File.Copy` works with them though.

Comment: if you can access it from the `windows explorer` this sounds like a permissions issue.. how is this being executed or run do you have a User account / permissions setup for `IIS_USER`

Comment: Take a look at this example of proper impersonation:  http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2006/07/windowsimpersonationcontext-made-easy/

Comment: "\NetworkPC\File.ppt" This is not a valid UNC path. I doubt you can access that path from explorer. Also, don't use WebClient to read a file. What about File.ReadAllBytes?

Answer (score 1):

`new Uri(@"\\NetworkPC\File.ppt")` results in `file://networkpc/File.ppt` which is not a network file path. You are using WebClient to access files which is a mistake to begin with. Use the usual file APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The File.Exists and File.Copy approach once I added this to the web.config:

More info:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158